# How to game calculate the time for completion of work?

Tags: android, ios, game-engine

i be wondering How to game calculate the time for completion of work?
e.x:clash of clans find something update are done.
i believe someone want say get the time by server.but even i be offline can receive notification which say done.even i do change clock of phone nothing change in game if i change time of phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time that is used to determine the yield from objects existing in clash of clans is maintained from a centralized server.
If you wanted to build an app that would calculate the times required to do things in game I think the rout to go would be to
`A) ask the developers for the code (unlikely to be fruitful)
B) reverse compile the code. (potentially illegal)
C) Hand document the times required for in game events to happen (game w/notes)
D) Do a literature review to find data on the game`

From this Data you may be able to craft a sort of clash of clans advisory app, but I doubt it will be easy to dupe such a consistently maintained app with hacks as simple as changing you're clock.

Comment: i don't want hack.it's just an example.i wrote some code.i want know how to  do protection.
what is a good app for reverse compile the code? tnx